# WPF scaleX and scaleY animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am trying to animation scaleX and scaleY on ellipse.
simply I want to animation scaleX and scaleY in 2 cases:

- When background is green I want to anmitaion scaleX and scaleY from 0 to 1.
- When background is red I want to animtaion scaleX and scaleY from 1 to 0

For some reason scale animation from 0 to 1 succeeded and from 1 to 0 didn't worked at all.

Code example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedEllipseON">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedEllipseScale">
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedEllipseScale">
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CheckedEllipseOFF">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedEllipseScale">
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedEllipseScale">
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.0" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">                            
                        <Ellipse Fill="Green" x:Name="CheckedEllipse" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" x:Name="CheckedEllipseScale"/>
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="Red">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedEllipseOFF}"/>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="Green">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedEllipseON}"/>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>                            
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyToggleButtonStyle}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
    <Button Command="{Binding TestCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

- Test property and TestCommand is only for changing colors green and red by boolean property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two different problems in the code you posted. First, your ellipse background is set explicitly to `"Green"` and so would never actually change to red. This is a case of the "locally set" property taking precedence over style or trigger setters.

This can be fixed by changing the ellipse declaration:

```xml
<Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
         x:Name="CheckedEllipse"
         RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
```

That will cause the ellipse to inherit the background value from the templated parent.

That issue affects only the color that is displayed. The triggers you are using use the `ToggleButton.Background`, and so are unaffected by that issue. So, why does the animation only work in one direction?

That issue is because you don't stop one animation before starting the other. The default for an animation is to hold its previous value, so once the animation runs to increase the scale, it continues to hold that scale value, causing the attempt by the other animation to reduce the scale to be overridden and ignored.

You can fix that aspect by adding `<StopStoryboard/>` actions to the triggers:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="Red">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryON"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedEllipseOFF}" Name="StoryOFF"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
  </DataTrigger>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="Green">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryOFF"/>
      <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedEllipseON}" Name="StoryON"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
  </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Note that you also have to give the *started* storyboard a name, so that you can use that name to stop it later.

With those changes, I'm able to click on the button to toggle the scale of the ellipse, causing it to increase in size when green, and decrease (and vanish) when red.